# MongoDB find then update - PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document that looks like

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("someId"),
  recipients: [
    {
      email: "emailaddress"
    },
    {
      email: "email2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to update the first recipient object, and add another property but to no avail.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("someId"),
  recipients: [
    {
      email: "emailaddress",
      new_prop: "something"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this with findOneAndUpdate? I am using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research. I'm new to MongoDB so I'm relying on my fellow developers to validate this code. I'm thinking this will do the trick:

```
$mongoID = new MongoID('yourID');
$newdata = array('$set' => array("recipients.0.new_prop" => "Something"));
$collection->update(array("_id" => $mongoID), $newdata);
```

It might help to visit this page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: My driver did not have the update function, only updateOne, but I used $elemMatch to target the subdocument in an array